# Plotting in latex

Tags: plot, graphs, charts, excel, engineering

I have to produce few charts a week and finding very hard/time consuming typing in code for plots using Tikz. Graphs i have to produce are simple,most of the time linear or exponential and does not consist allot of data.  Ploting in Excel seems so easy compared to Latex... I know that I can save my excel plot as image and include it to my latex file, but excel produces very different looking chart than latex

Is there a graphical interface software or tool that would speed up process? Having software to plot for me from data table would be my Latex dream come true

Comment: Are you using 'raw' TikZ or `pgfplots`? The latter is pretty straight-forward _provided_ you put in the initial effort to develop some re-usable outline files.

Comment: If you have the equation, plotting in `pgfplots` is as easy as pie. :)

Comment: im using Tikz however i have noticed that in my \usepackage i have pgfplots. So im not sure what i am using to be honest... Every plot it takes me couple of hours to do and what i am doing is googling most similar looking chart i could find and edit the code to suit my needs.

Comment: `\includegraphics{plot-made-with-excel}`

Comment: Most of my charts are experimental data with every point little off,so no linear relationship right away. I have to produce average line(trendline) with also displaying experimental data points.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to include an example or two of plots that you produced, along with the code. Then we should be able to suggest ways of simplifying the code and streamlining the process of producing plots by using styles.

Comment: @MariusKriauciunas **pgfplots** can take data from a table and plot it. TikZ also has data visualisation stuff, but **pgfplots** seems more powerful and flexible for the kind of thing you want. However, if you start by looking for something similar and then modifying the code without taking the time to understand and develop a strategy, then the process is likely to be both time-consuming and frustrating. You need to spend more time on one plot, say, to really understand it so that you know what you are doing. Then later plots will get easier and quicker. A single approach helps consistency.

Comment: The data visualisation stuff is described as 'more ambitious' than **pgfplots** but less mature and harder to use. It is described in part 4 of the TikZ manual.

Comment: If you can pick up enough R to use the ggplot2 package, you can then use the knitr package to produce excellent PDF reports each week by simply reading in your new data.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is also R, that is a software environment for statistical computing that can produce easily a **vast range of graphics** with a few lines of code.

Not surprisingly, you can use R separately to save graphs as `.png` or `.pdf` files, for later inclusions in LaTeX as normal images. But not so obvious, you can also insert R code between the LaTeX code in a file with the `.Rnw` extension, and thanks to R package `knitr`, this file is exported to a `.tex` version where original LaTeX code remain unaltered, but the R code is substituted by the result to be printed in LaTeX code.

In other words, if you write `2+3` as R code in between the `.Rnw` file,  you will obtain `5` (the R result) in the  `.tex` and `.pdf` version, and the same apply to plot functions, i.e., if you write this .Rnw file:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<mwe,echo=F>>=
library(chemCal)
data(massart97ex3)
m <- lm(y ~ x, data = massart97ex3)
calplot(m)
@
\end{document}
```

You should obtain this graph in the PDF file:

[image: mwe]

This big advantage of this method is that if you modify your data, you can update all the statistics and graphs just compiling again, so it is ideal for a automated reports. Another is the reproducible research: the original `.Rnw` of a paper allow to know how the results of this paper were obtained exactly.

Some editors as RStudio or LyX take care of the conversion process at the time of compile the PDF. Therefore, in the user side it is equally easy compile `.Rnw` or true LaTeX files.

Comment: @Marius Kriauciunas Just my opinion. I used R in my PhD thesis and I found it very hard to customize the plots. I also found it hard to find information about how to customize the plots. In my experience you are faster and more flexible if you use pgfplots or Excel.